# Flot within jquery qtip?

Tags: jquery, flot, qtip

I'm trying to replicate what Amazon, Trip Advisor etc are doing and showing a tooltip type interface when hovering over an average review score to show the breakdown of scores in bar chart format - on the qtip forums it's said to use Flot (my first time using it as normally use google charts) but whilst the graph renders fine on the page when I take it outside of the tooltip, as soon as I put the div within it it doesn't work.

My page is: http://solicitor.info/demo/solicitors/?id=15

Can anyone please see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When I hit your page, I get a javascript error:

```
Uncaught Invalid dimensions for plot, width = null, height = null
```

I'm guessing it is trying to render the plot while the "placeholder" div is still hidden inside the qtip.

I would try moving the `$.plot` call into a qtip [onShow](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#callbacks) callback.  That way you are sure the div is shown before trying to render the plot.

Comment: and obviously, @user759542, you should tell us in your question that you're getting an obviously related error :)

Comment: Sorry could you explain this a bit further please? Javascript isn't my strongest point :( and thanks Ryley, noted.

Comment: At the time your javascript is called to render the plot, the placeholder div (where the plot will be drawn) is a "hidden" element (it has display: none).  Since it is not actually on the screen it has no width and height.  Flot requires it to exist and have those properties set.