# Chart inside qtip tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, qtip2

I am trying to include a chart inside a qtip tooltip, but the chart does not show up in the tooltip. I have given the tooltip charting area an id of its own, but the plot does not appear in that area.

There is an [earlier posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275481/flot-within-jquery-qtip) on Stack Overflow which addresses the same issue, but the solution does not provide enough detail for me to apply it correctly. Likewise on the [qtip help forum](http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=80).

I made a fiddle demonstrating my problem. There is a normal tooltip and then a tooltip which is supposed to contain the chart (but doesn't).

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uho2Lzha/)

I'll also post the relevant code:

HTML:

```
<body>

Hello
<div id="hello1"></div>

<br style="margin-bottom: 50px;" />

<div id="hello2">Hello again!</div>

<br style="margin-bottom: 30px;" />

 </body>
```

CSS:

```
#hello1,
#hello2{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}

#tooltipchart{
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$('#hello1').qtip({ // Grab some elements to apply the tooltip to
content: { text: 'Here is a chart!'},
position: { target: 'mouse' }
})

$('#hello2').qtip({ 
content: { text: "No chart inside the tooltip :(" },
position: { target: 'mouse' },
api:{onShow: function(){return tooltipcontent();}}

})

function tooltipcontent(){
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("id", "tooltipchart");
div.setAttribute("height", "100px");
div.setAttribute("width", "100px");
return div;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var plot1 = $.jqplot('hello1', [
[[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]], {  
seriesDefaults: {
pointLabels: { show: true}
}
});

var plot2 = $.jqplot('tooltipchart', [
[[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]], {  
seriesDefaults: {
pointLabels: { show: true}
}
});    

});
```

Please advise on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the element first then you grab it to show in the tooltip.
If you copy the code below in jsfiddle it should work:

```
$('#hello1').qtip({ // Grab some elements to apply the tooltip to
    content: { text: 'Here is a chart!'},
    position: { target: 'mouse' }
})

$('#hello2').qtip({ 
    content: function(){return tooltipcontent();},
    position: { target: 'mouse' },
    api:{onShow: function(){return tooltipcontent();}}

})

function tooltipcontent(){
 return $("#tooltipchart").css('display','');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
 var plot1 = $.jqplot('hello1', [
        [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]], {  
        seriesDefaults: {
            pointLabels: { show: true}
            }
    });

 var div = document.createElement("div");
 div.setAttribute("id", "tooltipchart");
 div.setAttribute("height", "100px");
 div.setAttribute("width", "100px");
 $('body').append(div);
 var plot2 = $.jqplot('tooltipchart', [
        [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]], {  
        seriesDefaults: {
            pointLabels: { show: true}
            }
    });  
 $("#tooltipchart").css('display','none')  

});
```